# 2 Nvidia cards. How to switch xserver output on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, xorg

I have two Nvidia graphic cards in my computer. I want to use the slower one for my xserver and the faster one for computations with Cuda. However I don't know how to tell my Ubuntu 14.04 or my Nvidia Drivers which one to use for displaying the Xserver?

I was doing the same thing on a different computer recently. It was detecting automatically which one of the 2 graphic cards was attached to a monitor and chose that one for displaying the xserver.

This however doesn't work anymore on my current computer. (Maybe it's because the Bios is older)

Has anyone an idea?